# Does p-norm induce the standard topology?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $0<p<1$.

Define $d(x,y)=||x-y||_p^p$ for each $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Then, $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Does $d$ induce the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$? How do I prove it?

Comment: All norms on a finite-dimensional real or complex Banach space induce the same topology. Proving this is   not  really more difficult than any specific cases, and with essentially the same methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first see why $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Clearly, $d(x,y)=0\iff \sum_{1\leq i\leq n}|x_{i}-y_{i}|^{p}=0\iff |x_{i}-y_{i}|=0$ for all $1\leq i\leq n\iff x_{i}=y_{i}$ for all $1\leq i\leq n\iff x=y$.

Equally obvious is the fact that $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$.

But what about the triangle inequality: $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$?

We start with a lemma.

**Lemma.** For all $a,b\geq 0$, $(a+b)^{p}\leq a^{p}+b^{p}$.

*Proof.* Let $\phi(x)=(1+x)^{p}-1-x^{p}$ for $x\geq 0$. Then, $\phi'(x)=p(1+x)^{p-1}-px^{p-1}$. Since $0<p<1, p-1<0$, so that $(1+x)^{p}<x^{p-1}$. Thus, $\phi'(x)<0$ for $0<x<\infty$, and hence, $\phi$ is decreasing. Therefore, given $a,b\geq 0$,

$$
0=\phi(0)\geq\phi\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\left(1+\frac{a}{b}\right)^{p}-1-\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{p}=\frac{(a+b)^{p}-b^{p}-a^{p}}{b^{p}}.
$$

Thus, $(a+b)^{p}\leq a^{p}+b^{p}$.//

Now, the triangle inequality is easy:
$$
d(x,y)=\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\sum}|x_{i}-y_{i}|^{p}=\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\sum}|x_{i}-z_{i}+z_{i}-y_{i}|^{p}\leq\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\sum}|x_{i}-z_{i}|^{p}+\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\sum}|z_{i}-y_{i}|^{p}=d(x,z)+d(z,y).
$$

Therefore, $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Now, by the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, I assume you are referring to the topology generated by open balls; i.e., the topology generated by your metric $\|x-y\|_{2}$. We'll show that they generate the same topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. For $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, let $B_{d}(x,\epsilon)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}|d(x,y)<\epsilon\}$ and let $B_{2}(x,\epsilon)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}|\|x-y\|_{2}<\epsilon\}$. We will show that $\exists\delta_{1},\delta_{2}> 0$ such that $B_{d}(0,\delta_{1})\subseteq B_{2}(0,\epsilon)$ and $B_{2}(0,\delta_{2})\subseteq B_{d}(0,\epsilon)$.

Assume WLOG that $\epsilon\leq 1$. Let $\delta_{1}=\sqrt{\epsilon}$. Suppose $x\in B_{p}(0,\delta_{1})$. Then,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\sum}|x_{i}|^{p}<\epsilon&\implies |x_{i}|^{p}\leq\epsilon\leq 1 \text{ for all } 1\leq i\leq n\\
&\implies |x_{i}|^{2}\leq |x_{i}|^{p}\text{ for all } 1\leq i\leq n\\
&\implies \|x\|_{2}<\|x\|_{p}^{p}<\delta_{1}=\epsilon.
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus, $B_{p}(0,\delta_{1})\subseteq B_{2}(0,\epsilon)$.

Now, let $\delta_{2}=\left(\frac{\epsilon}{n}\right)^{1/p}$. Suppose $x\in B_{2}(0,\delta_{2})$. Then,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\|x\|_{2}<\delta_{2}&\implies\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\sum}|x_{i}|^{2}<\delta_{2}^{2}\\
&\implies \underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\sum}|x_{i}|^{p}\leq n\cdot\max\{|x_{i}|^{p}\}=n\cdot\max\{|x_{i}|^{2}\}^{p/2}<n\cdot(\delta_{2}^{2})^{p/2}=\epsilon.
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore, $B_{2}(0,\delta_{2})\subseteq B_{p}(0,\epsilon)$.//